# On Certain Android devices, the app opens unexpectedly

Tags: android

I am testing my app on several android devices

and on some of the devices, it seems to load the app unexpectedly

I have a "UserPresent" Intent filter on one of my receivers, but that is for push notifications

What can I do to find what is causing this problem?
and why it appears only on some devices, and not all ?

```
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>




  <receiver
        android:name="com.myapp.receivers.Receiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Is there any other receiver in the manifest?

Comment: yes  there is another receiver in the application, and it's a copy of this one